# Unable to change the language to Java in Android while creating new project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to android Studio. I am trying to create new project in java language. But the language is set to kotlin by default. The drop down does not work. What shall I do? Can someone help me out here?

I am trying to create new project in java language.
The drop down does not work from which i can choose the language.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look towards the top of that screenshot, you chose the "Empty Compose Activity" template. That uses Jetpack Compose for its UI, and Jetpack Compose requires Kotlin. You will need to choose a different starter template if you wish to use Java.

Or, consider learning Kotlin, as Kotlin is the long-term direction for Android app development. FWIW, [here is a free book of mine on Kotlin](https://commonsware.com/Kotlin/).

Answer (score 1):

[image: Empty Activity]

Why don't you create "Empty Activity" for learning android studio.
Starting with "Empty Activity" is good for understanding this IDE.
I did the same way when I was starting.
Hope this would help you.

Comment: Yes! I tried it and it worked out!! Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

straight forward for your problem
as you see the android studio didn't recognize the java path from your PC or you didn't install android studio fully maybe it's customized so you have 2 way

1. if you have installed java JDK already you will need to make links between android studio and java, somehow maybe in the config
2. you didn't install java yet so (you need to install Java JDK)

[install-setup-android-studio-java-jdk-sdk BY techpassmaster](https://techpassmaster.com/install-setup-android-studio-java-jdk-sdk/)

this the closest link I got containing all of steps you need individually